# SUMIFS with three criteria

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to write a SUMIFS formula that will aggregate my data based on three criteria. As per the first table, I am presented with data that provide the sales for each agent, broken down by three dimensions: product, year and month.

I have a report on sheet 2, which contain each product in the rows and year in the columns. Furthermore, cell C1 indicates which month the sales data represents, and ideally I want the report to update based on the value entered in that cell.

In cells B4:C5, I have tried the following formula:

`=SUMIFS(Sheet 1!$B$4:$I$6,Sheet 1!$1:$1,A4,Sheet 1!$2:$2,B3,Sheet 1!$3:$3,$C$1)`

But its giving me an error. I have a feeling that my sum range in SUMIFS formula is not correct, can anyone help me verify?

Sheet 1

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  | Product A | Product A | Product B | Product B | Product A | Product A | Product B | Product B |
| 2 |  | 2012 | 2012 | 2012 | 2012 | 2013 | 2013 | 2013 | 2013 |
| 3 |  | Jan | Feb | Jan | Feb | Jan | Feb | Jan | Feb |
| 4 | Agent A | 11 | 5 | 6 | 15 | 2 | 16 | 9 | 18 |
| 5 | Agent B | 15 | 14 | 5 | 3 | 18 | 6 | 20 | 2 |
| 6 | Agent C | 13 | 19 | 15 | 18 | 20 | 6 | 4 | 8 |

Sheet 2

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 |  |  | Jan |
| 2 |  |  |  |
| 3 |  | 2012 | 2013 |
| 4 | Product A | 39 | 40 |
| 5 | Product B | 26 | 33 |

Answer (score 1):

***This solves the issue:***

**:Caveat:**

- *Just for proper data orientation I've altered the Column Headings in Sheet 1.*
- *In place of SUMIF I've used SUMPRODUCT, which is better to control & faster too.*

[image]

- Formula in cell B11 in Sheet 2:

  ```
  =SUMPRODUCT((Sheet1!$B$1:$I$1=$A11)*(Sheet1!$B$2:$I$2=B$9)*(Sheet1!$B$3:$I$3=B$10)*(Sheet1!$B$4:$I$6))
  ```

**N.B.**

- Fill the formula across the range.
- adjust cell references in the formula as needed.